# Lyx Missing character unclear log: "There is no e (U+0065) in font rsfs10!"

Tags: errors, lyx, line-numbering, missing

I am using Lyx to write a paper and so far i did not had any problems. I wrote some sections,  export in PDF results is ok
Then i added some other sections did the export PDF and I got error "mising glyphs!" three times (1st picture)
The Lyx Latex LOG file contains the list of warnings and errors (other pictures) but i do not find the line-number of the LyxEditor line where the character error is located so is not trivial to recover (as i wrote several section before the next export)
Do you have an idea how to find the exact line in my Lyx Editor window (or in the LATEX export) where this missing char happened?
thank you a lot for your kind support

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome! The message is not surprising, because the font has just the uppercase letters.

Comment: thx ... how to know where this bad carachter is insert in the code?

Comment: Sorry, but LyX is something I don't even consider looking at.

Comment: thank you anyway! However, if I have understood the error correctly, it is a character that is only capitalised (uppercase only)  and has been used with a lower case letter in the document... am i right? it is already a clue...

Answer (score 2):

I've solved at the end...
i removed some line of text till the error disappeared. It was in fact something really weird: at the end of a mathematical formula i should have typed a forbidden character (probably somehting available only in capital letter). Lyx did not recognize and put an empty char. This is evident only if you click on the formula, put the cursor at the end and you see an empty box underlined (means there is still a used space in the formula). During the compilation it give this error.
[image]